# Discussion Forum Theme is stuck on Default

Tags: forum, discussion

Even though I have changed the default theme to something else, for me and me only, it is stuck on the old theme. When I log in as another member, I see the new forum theme, but as soon as I switch back to my account I see the old theme still. Is there a database table created where it associates that particular member with that theme? If so, where can I find it?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Found out why. You just need to revert the 'forum_theme' in the 'exp_members table' to NULL and then multiple forums will work with their default theme instead of being explicitly set to one theme throughout.